# Orbeon 2020.1.2 CE and TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, windows-ce, orbeon

My agency is developing using the CE version in anticipation of purchasing a license. We are creating xforms by hand using the 2019 CE version, using jsp's in a Java tomcat application (separate deployment). I downloaded the 2020 version (hoping to use the 5.x version of TinyMCE) and found that rich text controls no longer appear using the same xforms used with the 2019 version. Looking at the browser page inspector (Ms edge), it appears that the TinyMCE resources (js and css) aren't downloaded to the browser at all. No html elements are created for the editor. I didn't see a console error or see an http error for the resources.

I couldn't find any issues related to TinyMCE in this version. Has anyone else seen this? Is there a configuration difference between the versions that may be causing it? (I reused the configuration I had from 2019 version). Anyone have suggestions on what to look at?

When I reverted to the 2019 version it works again. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By "separate deployment" are you saying that you have an application that generates XForms, and that you send it to processing for processing to Orbeon Forms, this instead of using Form Builder to create the forms?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any issue with the TinyMCE and Orbeon Forms CE 2020.1.2. I would recommend you try to reproduce this with an out-of-the-box install, and if it works there, progressively put back your existing configuration on that out-of-the-box install.

If you are doing this with the perspective of using Orbeon Forms PE, I would just use the latest release of Orbeon Forms PE 2020.1.3 with a trial license, as this way you'll have a configuration that is as close as possible to what you're ultimately planning to have, and you will benefit from having all the latest released fixes.

(And should this not solve the problem, feel free to post more information in the comments.)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply.  I have tried redoing this, but it turns out as far as configuration goes I wasn't using the config file I thought I was, I was using the default production was, so they were the same in both instances. As before, if I go to the Orbeon "Form Runner" app to look at the sample of controls, it does display the tinymce editor correctly.

Comment: @FrancisParsons Excellent , I'm glad you solved that problem with the TinyMCE, and thank you for the update. -Alex

Comment: Sorry, by accident not all of my post got posted.  It doesn't work with an Xforms jsp still: the only error I saw in the browser " http://localhost:8080/leaf-forms/orbeon/xforms-server/Hint.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE". (Doesn't appear with 2019 version). It it does look like the TinyMCE code exists in the Orbeon js files, but no editor gets instantiated at all. (There is no editor HTML). I didn't see anything in the orbeon.log that pointed to anything other than the "Hint.min.js.map". I did set the "TINY_MCE_CONFIG" options.

Comment: @FrancisParsons Are you saying that you have a JSP file that produces XForms, which uses the `<fr:tinymce>`? You are not creating the form in Form Builder and publishing it? (This is a similar question to the one I posted on June 8 as a comment to your question, which you can see above.) -Alex

Comment: Yes we are creating xForms and not using FormBuilder, and are using the Xform textarea tag. (I did try using <fr: tinymce> in the .jsp too, but no difference.).  I was surprised there were no errors in the orbeon.log or in the browser console, although the tinymce code does seem to get delivered (I can get the version from the console). I didn't see anything amiss in the orbeon.log on startup either. I looked for configuration differences but could find none, it was using the same the default properties (prod). I guess I should try the trial PE version?

Comment: Got it! You are not seeing the component even being initialized, because the code to do so isn't present anymore at the XForms level, and has instead been moved to the Form Runner level, which is the one used for forms produced by Form Builder. Could this component be made to work at the XForms level? Maybe, for now. But to be inline with the component namespace, and to prepare for the case when the component might need to use something that is only available in Form Runner, like the current language, the component has been moved to the Form Runner level.

Comment: Could it make sense to have your code generate a form in the Form Runner format?

Comment: Hmm. We would very much like to continue developing in XForms rather than Form Runner, and we do need to use this editor. So when we purchase the PE license (pending), the newest version will not support this? Could we still use the earlier version where it does work? Have you gotten any other feedback about the loss of this functionality? Are there any possible workarounds we could implement to get this to work?

Comment: @FrancisParsons The change is the same in both the CE and PE. Yes, I think that, for now, your only option is to use an earlier version of Orbeon Forms, before this code was moved to be at the "Form Runner level". BTW, I am not sure the change was done very much intentionally: the code was rewritten from JavaScript to Scala.js, and since this is a `fr:*` component, we put it at the "Form Runner level". We haven't heard from anyone else having this problem, for this component, but had a similar situation for the `fr:date`, and we moved that code back to XForms. -Alex