# XForm schema validation: resolution of child schema imports

Tags: orbeon

I'm interested in using schema-based validation:

```
<model schema="oxf:..path">
```

The Orbeon documention currently doesn't have a lot of details about it's use, and in one spot this topic shows up as a "TODO". The schemas we created all have child schemas (certain elements are common to all).

I have a folder structure for the schemas that looks like:

```
COMMON
   xsd
   xsd...
schema_A
   xsd

<schema_B>
    xsd
...
```

I am putting these schema in a Maven project that generates a jar file of these, and am putting this JAR in "orbeon/web-inf/lib" folder.  In the xforms, I have no problems accesing individual files in this JAR (like creating an instance with that as a source).
In the schemas themselves I'm using a relative url that uses "directory up", like this:

```
<import xmlns="<uri>"  "schemaLocation="<uri> ../../COMMON/childSchemaA.xsd">
```

However, Orbeon doesn't seem to be able to resolve the imports and I get a "Resource not Found" page when I try to use it. In the orbeon log I see that it interprets the location as being in the parent folder, i.e. "schemaA/childSchema.xsd"
Is this a known issue? (I am using the lasT Orbeon 2019 version as the current version does not support rich text controls in XForms). I did a test in which I put the parent schemas and child schemas in the same folder (in the jar file), and validation seems to work as expected.

Is there something that would help orbeon resolve the child schemas? For organization reasons, I don't want to have to have a folder with all of the parent schemas and the child schemas in a single folder. I have another Java web project in which the same JAR file is put on the classpath, and when using the parent schemas for validation there are not any issues.

Comment: Hi Francis, my understanding is that you have the directory `COMMON` at the same level as `schema_A`. So if from `schema_A/file_A.xsd` you want to refer to `COMMON/file_COMMON.xsd`, you'll want to write `../COMMON/file_COMMON.xsd`. So in you path you'll want to have `..`, not `../..`. Could the solution be as simple as that? -Alex

Comment: Also, you're saying "the current version does not support rich text controls in XForms". Could you elaborate on that? What is the problem you're seeing with rich text controls on 2020.1.x? -Alex

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. In the "sketch" of the folder structure, I simplified it, but each "documents/schema/docNameX/" folder actually has three subfolders, "xml", "xsd", and "xfr", with the schema in the "xsd" folder. So it does actually need to go two steps up to get to the "COMMON" folder. As I mentioned, the import location does work in my XML editor, but also in a (Spring) web application that uses the same JAR file.

Comment: In regards to the "Rich text" issue, I asked about this in another SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861807/orbeon-2020-1-2-ce-and-tinymce . In this comment you said "Yes, I think that, for now, your only option is to use an earlier version of Orbeon Forms, before this code was moved to be at the "Form Runner level". BTW, I am not sure the change was done very much intentionally: the code was rewritten from JavaScript to Scala.js, and since this is a fr:* component, we put it at the "Form Runner level". "

Comment: Got it Francis about the folder structure requiring a `../..` instead of just `..`. And also about the `<fr:tinymce>` now having Scala.js code at the Form Runner level, so you can't use it in plain XForms anymore. This is still something that we could take care of, but just would need to allocate the time to do so. Your organization wouldn't be using Orbeon Forms PE by any chance (instead of Orbeon Forms CE)? I'm asking, as this would make it easier from a time allocation perspective.

Comment: Getting back to the issue with including a XSD using a relative path, would you be able to create a minimal example with a very simple XForms file, that uses a first XSD, which includes a second XSD, showing that if both are in the same directory think that working, but if the second XSD is in the parent directory then the include fails? And you could maybe put stows 3 files in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com). -Alex

Comment: Re:<fr:tinymce>: We are planning on buying the PE license soon, but I don't know the details on exactly when (I believe we would be purchasing 5 licenses).  We have been using a CE version since the development towards demonstrating the feasibility of using Orbeon would take much longer than the trial period.

Comment: Re:<fr:tinymce>: We are planning on buying 5 PE licenses soon, but I don't know the details on exactly when.  We have been using a CE version since the development towards demonstrating the feasibility of using Orbeon would take much longer than the trial period. We would like to be using the most current version maintenance and support reasons.

Do you feel that the number of users coding is plain xforms is too small to continue supporting the rich text control? This feature is quite important to us, but we also would like to use plain Xforms for greater flexibility.

Comment: Re: putting example in a Gist: Unfortunately, I just discovered our agency firewall is blocking Gist.  Is there another method that would be convenient? I would like to prepare a "pared down" example to help you evaluate whether this is happening, and it would also help me rule out whether the problem is due to how the schemas are written.  I would anticipate that it would take 3 schema files, an xForm file (is ".jsp" OK?), and the .jar file containing the schemas.

Comment: Got it about Gist. I think you should be able to reproduce the problem with 1 XForms files + 2 XSD files, and each file could be very, very short, so what about you put the content of those 3 files in the body of your questions above, with an indication of where they should deployed, in a verbatim install of Orbeon Forms (i.e. `WEB-INF/resouces/…`)? -Alex

Comment: I will try preparing a minimal example soon, I just haven't gotten the time. I thought a key part of this is that the schemas are stored in a jar file (in orbeons web-inf/lib folder).  I'll let you know.

Comment: Sounds good Francis. -Alex

Comment: Alex - I have tried a simple schema that has nothing to do with the ones I'm acutally using, and tried to have the parent schema use other schemas, and it did actually work.  The schemas I'm using are broken into parts, and they reference each other (Saxon validator in my editor gives warnings "schema x was not loaded because it is already available"), but standard Java validates XML successfully with them).

Comment: I get this kind of error from Orbeon when the child schemas are in a folder up: "2021-11-19 12:02:53,600 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - not found {controller: "oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-renderer-page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/xforms-renderer", resource: "/documents/schema/XFPG1/xsd/QUEUE_DATA.xsd"}". However, the path for "QUEUE_DATA" should be "/documents/schema/COMMON/QUEUE_DATA.xsd". If I put all the child schemas in the same folder as the parent schema, this doesn't happen.

Comment: I should note that the test schema I constructed are very simple compared to what I was using. I was hoping I could show the error with just a few files. I could try adding things bit by bit until I hit the error, but this would take a really long time to do, and I was hoping you might recognize something else going on that would explain it.  I could also just give up and put all the schemas in the same folder, but I wouldn't know anything more about what I did wrong and I'll wonder if I'll later regret the decision.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi Francis, this issue really doesn't ring a bell. I can imagine that there could be a bug whereby if you have file A, using file B, using file C, Orbeon Forms is resolving the relative path to C (which is in B), not relative to the location of B as it should, but relative to the location of A instead. It would be nice to pinpoint what the problem is, but like you said, you're maybe better off just putting all the files in the same directory. -Alex

Comment: Also, if you narrow down the bug to something that we can reproduce, and ultimately fix, the fix will most likely only be in our latest code, which you won't be able to update to until we also make further changes to the `<fr:tinymce>` so it can be used from plain XForms. Just something else to be aware of ;). -Alex

Comment: I have started doing that, moving all the schemas to the same folder. In my previous test, I had all the "child" schemas literally at the same folder level.  This time, I put the child schemas into a folder called "COMMON".  ("main_schema.xsd" imports "COMMON/DOC_PROPS.xsd").  However, the log showed this : "PageFlowControllerProcessor  - not found {controller: "oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-renderer-page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/xforms-renderer", resource: "/documents/schema/DOC_PROPS.xsd"} Well! I'll try putting the child schema in the same folder to confirm that this still works.

Comment: Hi Francis, yes, maybe just putting all the schemas in the same folder is the way to go. You'll let me know if this works for you. -Alex